# How to make Job attribute value based on environment

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

In ansible cron job definition,how to give job attribute value dynamically based on  environment.I have requiremnt need to execute same cronjob with different parameters and to do that right now defining two different cron jobs, one is for prod and other is for UAT,DEV. Is there anyway where we can define one job for all the env and change the job value based on the env

Written code like below

```
name: Ensure a job that runs purge backup for UAT,DEV and QA
  cron:
    name: "Cassandra purge backup job"
    user: cassandra
    minute: 0
    hour: 3
    weekday: "5,6"
    job: "/usr/ops/base/bin/cron.sh /usr/ops/cassandra/bin/backupfiles.sh /nas_csd_backup/uat_backup 7"
  when: cassandra_backup_enable
  with_items:
    - dev
    - qa
    - uat

name: Ensure a job that runs purge backup for PROD
  cron:
    name: "Cassandra purge backup job"
    user: cassandra
    minute: 0
    hour: 3
    weekday: "5,6"
    job: "/usr/ops/base/bin/cron.sh /usr/ops/cassandra/bin/backupfiles.sh /nas_csd_backup/prod_backup 7 /nas_csd_backup/prod_keep_backup 365"
  when: cassandra_backup_enable
  with_items:
    - production
```

In the above code all parameters are same except "job".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ternary filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8).

This should work:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    cassandra_backup_enable: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: > # multiline operator
          /usr/ops/base/bin/cron.sh /usr/ops/cassandra/bin/backupfiles.sh /nas_csd_backup/prod_backup 7
          {{ (item in ['dev', 'qa', 'uat']) | ternary('', '/nas_csd_backup/prod_keep_backup 365') }}
      loop:
        - dev
        - qa
        - uat
        - production

    - name: Ensure a job that runs purge backup
      cron:
        name: "Cassandra purge backup job"
        user: cassandra
        minute: 0
        hour: 3
        weekday: "5,6"
        job: > # multiline operator
          /usr/ops/base/bin/cron.sh /usr/ops/cassandra/bin/backupfiles.sh /nas_csd_backup/prod_backup 7
          {{ (item in ['dev', 'qa', 'uat']) | ternary('', '/nas_csd_backup/prod_keep_backup 365') }}
      when: cassandra_backup_enable
      loop:
        - dev
        - qa
        - uat
        - production
```

Comment: So if it is other than prod it will take default value otherwise will it append string whatever mentioned in the ternary operator? if that is the case are we giving empty string as first parameter for ternary operator?

Comment: `bool | ternary(value_1, value_2)` will have `value_1` if `bool` is `True` or `value_2` if `bool` is `False`.

Comment: job: >
        {{ (cassandra_purge_backup_enable_prod) | ternary(
          '/usr/ops/base/bin/cronic.sh /usr/ops/cassandra/bin/TH_Purge_Backupfiles.sh /nas_csd_backup/uat_backup 7', 
          '/usr/ops/base/bin/cronic.sh /usr/ops/cassandra/bin/TH_Purge_Backupfiles.sh /nas_csd_backup/prod_backup 7 /nas_csd_backup/prod_keep_backup 
          ') }}  is it making sense?